# Reset Pagination on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

`wp_reset_postdata` and `wp_reset_query` restores global $post variable.
How do I reset $paged variable which is used in pagination?

OR

How can I get back to www.example.com/page/1 from any page like www.example.com/page/32?

Comment: `set_query_var('paged', 1);`

Comment: Where should I use it? before query function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do this on my site by doing this

```
$wp_query->set('paged', 1);
```

where $wp_query is your WP_Query object you're querying. You would do this AFTER you defined $wp_query in your code.